# Mysql query not working, Updating a column

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I am executing the following code, but `cash` field is not getting updated:

```
c.execute("UPDATE users 
            SET cash = %s 
            WHERE username = %s",
          (amount, thwart(session.get('username'))))
```

Comment: cash column is not updating.

Comment: unless you are validating and escaping your input data, this query can easily be subjected to SQL injection. Use single quotes for %s. Also, ensure that the username being entered, exists in the table, for cash field to be updated

Comment: `%s` in `WHERE username = %s` should have quotes around it e.g. `WHERE username = '%s'`